# Отслеживать изменение строки

Tags: android, строки, static

Есть ли какой-то метод или способ отслеживания изменения переменной, в моем случае строки ? У меня метод с изменением нужной строки вызывается из другого класса, поэтому он *public static*. Не статичный метод с сохранением из него не вызвать, но и сделать его таким я не могу, так как придется статичными делать и *Shared Preferences*, и все, что связано с ними. Думаю это не грамотно. Знаю, что существует метод отслеживания фокуса в *Edit Text*, так вот мне интересно, есть ли все-таки что-то подобное для постоянного отслеживания изменения строки ?

Comment: Если речь о строке, которая записывается в `SharedPreferences`, то можно назначить колбек `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. Кое-какие пояснения в гайде по настройкам: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/use-saved-values#listen_for_changes_to_preference_values . Статья на англ. о применении с `livedata` и `Rx`: https://medium.com/@jurajkunier/android-shared-preferences-listener-implemented-by-rxjava-and-livedata-cfac02683eac

Answer (score 0):

Стандартных средств для отслеживания изменений в строке нет. Вообще, строки - иммутабельны и их нельзя изменить, только заменить. Отследить замену тоже нельзя.

Для решения такого рода задач вам нужно использовать такие паттерны как `Singleton` и `Observer`. Самостоятельно их можно реализовать, но лучше использовать уже готовые решения.

`Singleton` можно реализовать, например, средствами к-л DI либы. Например Toothpick.

`Observer` - через RxJava + RxRelay.

Если кратко - биндите экземпляр BehaiviorRelay через DI, указываете ему быть `Singleton`-ом, инжектите в нужные места и устанавливаете ему значения и/или подписываетесь на получение изменений в нём.