# Как сделать общую переменную у сервиса и активности

Tags: java, android

Пробовал сделать с помощью `BroadcastReceiver`'а в деятельностях, т.е отправлять ее при изменении, но вышло криво и работало не очень правильно. Есть ли другой способ? Кстати, унаследоваться невозможно.

Comment: Вот тут описан общий подход к решению такого рода задач: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1155103/17609

Comment: в активности объявляете переменную как, например, public static int MyInt, в сервисе прописываете в блоке импорта import Mypackage.MyActivity.MyInt

Comment: @DrMcSheen зачем же такую жуть советовать ?!

Comment: @keekkenen, уж несколько лет приложение так прекрасно работает, в чём жуть-то?

Answer (score 0):

Надо сделать [Service binding](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) - связывание `Activity` и `Service` - в итоге можно иметь в `Activity` указатель на экземпляр службы - следовательно и легко реализовать общую переменную.